# Como alternar entre true e false o checked de um input?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho este código e gostaria de alternar entre true e false o atributo **checked** do input. Estranhamente está pegando o `id` do `label` porque o web designer sobrepôs o `label` ao `input`.

```
(function($){
    $("label").click(
        function(){
            var idcheck = $(this).attr("for");
            $("input[id="+idcheck+"]").attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Até onde me lembro, no jQuery versão 1.6 ou superior `checked` é tratado como propriedade e não como atributo - ou seja, você obtém e altera com o método `prop` e não `attr`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eu usaria o seguinte código:

```
/* Não precisa de JavaScript! */
```

Ou seja, nenhum código! Se o seu label já tem o atributo `for` apontando para o input, não é necessário usar JS. O comportamento padrão do clique no label é justamente inverter o estado do checkbox. Exemplo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xeaags2/1/)

O código que você postou parece ter sido criado para tentar impedir que o checkbox seja desmarcado (todo clique termina com ele `checked`).

Comment: @KaduAmaral Obrigado pelo jsfiddle!

Answer (score 5):

Sugiro remover de todo o atributo `checked`.

```
(function ($) {
    $("label").click(function () {
        var idcheck = $(this).attr("for");
        $("input[id=" + idcheck + "]").removeAttr('checked'); // <--
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Ou outra alternativa, semelhante (dar valor `false`):

```
(function ($) {
    $("label").click(function () {
        var idcheck = $(this).attr("for");
        $("input[id=" + idcheck + "]").prop("checked", "false"); // <--
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta pois entendeu errado devido ao que estava escrito. Obrigado por reconsiderar uma nova resposta e ótimo domingo.

Answer (score 4):

use `$("input[id="+idcheck+"]").prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta pois entendeu errado devido ao que estava escrito. Obrigado por reconsiderar uma nova resposta e ótimo domingo.

Answer (score 4):

Tente isso:

```
Teste: <input type="checkbox" id="ck" checked/>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#ck").attr('checked', false); 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Se o webdesigner não fez "trabalho extra" não era para você ter problema e nem ser necessário script para setar o check. Mas caso realmente seja mais fácil adaptar o script do que ter que revisar o código...

Não use attr. Pois atributos não funcionam legal com "propriedades vivas" invés disso use prop() como sugeriu o nosso amigo Sergio e wriel.

```
$("label").click(function () {
     var idcheck = $(this).attr("for");
     $("input[id=" + idcheck + "]").prop("checked", "false"); // <--
});
```

Caso utilize o attr, depois de alterar o status algumas vezes vai parar de funcionar. Já tive este problema e já te adianto, para lhe evitar dor de cabeça. O prop, sempre vai trazer o status atual, já o attr pode se perder na memória, e não refletir o atual momento.

[Aqui tem mais detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar esse mesmo código apenas com algumas alterações na hora que você muda o "checked".

```
(function($){
    $("label").click(
        function(){
            var idcheck = $(this).attr("for");

            var checkedStatus = $("input[id="+idcheck+"]").attr("checked"); // Aqui eu pego o valor atual do checked no input
            $("input[id="+idcheck+"]").attr("checked", !checkedStatus); // e atribuo um novo valor invertendo o valor antigo
        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

Nesse caso ele sempre vai inverter o valor do checked do input:

- Se o checked do input for true ele vai setar o novo valor como false.
- Se o checked do input for false ele vai setar o novo valor como true.

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$( "input[type='checkbox']:odd" ).attr( "checked", "true" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de apanhar um pouco consegui resolver de uma maneira bacana: usando a negação.

```
document.getElementById("Checkbox").checked = !document.getElementById("contatoCheckbox").checked;
```